# Converting Ruby's yield inside of nested functions into Node.js

Tags: javascript, ruby, node.js, yield

I'm trying to convert a chunk of Ruby code into Node.js. One particular piece has me stumped, concerning `yield`. The code goes like this:

```
each_pair(hash["args"][0]) do |key, value, pair|
   # perform operations
end

...


def each_pair(hash)
    hash["props"].each do |p|
        yield(p["key"], p["value"], p)
    end
end
```

If I am reading this code correctly, it's saying "Iterate over the hash properties. For every element, call back out to the outer function and perform the operation with the given `p["key"], p["value"], p` values."

I can't really comprehend how this would look in Javascript. I'm acquainted with writing more trivial closures. Is a conversion possible at all? I'm guessing it's something like:

```
each_pair(hash["args"][0], function(key, value, pair) {
 // perform operations
}

...

function each_pair(hash, func) {
   hash["props"].forEach(p) {
       func(p["key"], p["value"], p)
   }
}
```

But something doesn't feel right...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that's an OK translation. It's a little deceptive because any method in ruby can be called with an implicit block. If it's there, you can `yield` it. It's one of those shorthand tricks that you forget if you don't use them for a while :)

In the ruby version, you could also add a `&block` argument and replace `yield(...` with `block.call(...`. It'd be functionally equivalent.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the validation. Is there anything that can turn this from an "ok" translation into a good one?

Comment: This is at the edge of my JS knowledge so maybe somebody else'd like to chip in... but [JavaScript 1.7](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/1.7) has a `yield` keyword.