# Does exists a yield_self function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, ruby

Just out of curiosity as a Rubyist I wondered if JavaScript had something like the yield_self method of ruby.

```
"value".yield_self { |v| v[0] + v[4]}
=> "ve"
```

Which is a chainable method that uses the "object" you've called it on as value (super rough description)
More examples: https://zverok.github.io/blog/2018-01-24-yield_self.html

I know that we have similar behaviour in Promises but I can imagine using it without Promise

```
"value".yieldSelf(v => v[0] + v[4])
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12490812/converting-rubys-yield-inside-of-nested-functions-into-node-js#

Comment: This question is kind of pointless without specifying which version of javascript we are talking about. Even at that the answer is probaly no unless you plan to use a polyfill or you are targeting a server side javascript implementation.

Comment: @max as I said it's only out of curiosity purposes. I mean, any version of JS should be ok, until ES10 and later if someone came here in few years. It's ok even to mention third party libraries. No need to worry about polyfills, I'm not interested in using it on old browsers or kinda, that's not the question

Comment: @max how is this pointless? He's asking if javascript has that feature/syntactic sugar, I don't see why he should specify the version of javascript. The answer may not be version-specific at all, and even if it was the answer can be in a from of "Yes since ES{X}". If somebody asked if javascript had promises, would you say that the question is useless? or would you answer "Yes, since version XX. Before that you can use polyfills"?

Comment: Chill out. There is no such function in any version I am aware of - neither is there one on the standards track. Since its a prototype based language you can easily create one with `Object.prototype.yieldSelf = function(callback){ return callback(this) };`. But yeah augmenting prototypes is evil.

Comment: Its also not really that useful in javascript with its strange handling of `this` and lack of true blocks (arrow function are not quite the same thing) and lack of a good functional standard library like Ruby has.

Comment: It is generally not a good idea to ask about "feature from language X in language Y". Instead, you should simply provide a precise, unambiguous, objective, complete specification of what you are looking for. For two reasons: 1) If you simply ask for "feature from language X in language Y", you significantly reduce the pool of potential answerers to only people who are experts in *both* X and Y. And 2) there are *always* subtle differences between languages, so the answer is *always* "No", unless you provide a precise, unambiguous, objective, complete specification of which aspects you want …

Comment: … to include and which aspects are irrelevant, at which point you may just as well just specify the desired goal without any reference to language X in the first place. In this particular case, for example, `Object#yield_self` takes a block argument. ECMAScript doesn't have blocks, so clearly, this is already out of the question. In case you don't pass a block, it returns an `Enumerator`. ECMAScript doesn't have those either. So, the answer is clearly "No", but there may still be some equivalent to some sub-aspect, but you will have to say which aspects you care about.

Comment: Thank you @JörgWMittag, for your answer and your politeness. Yes you're right. Great explanation about my mistakes regarding the question.